# Java reflection - enum generate

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I make program which can generate source code of class,enum and interfaces using reflection but I have problem with Enum generating.

My EumTest class

```
public enum EnumTest{
a,b;

private  String r;

private EnumTest(){

}

private void some(){

}

public int[] some2(int[] b){
    return b;
}
}
```

Method which generate enum file

```
private void generateEnum(Class<?> cls,PrintWriter writer) {
    this.writePackage(cls, writer);
    this.writeAnnotations(writer, cls.getDeclaredAnnotations());
    writer.write(Modifier.toString(cls.getModifiers())+ " enum " + cls.getSimpleName());
    this.writeImplementation(cls, writer);
    writer.write("{");
    this.writeNewLine(writer);
    Object[] cons = cls.getEnumConstants();
    for (int i = 0; i < cons.length; i++) {
        writer.write(cons[i].toString());
        if(i != cons.length - 1)
            writer.write(",");
    }
    writer.write(";");
    this.writeNewLine(writer);
    this.writeFields(cls, writer);
    this.writeConstructors(cls, writer);
    this.writeMethods(cls,writer);
    writer.write("}");
}
```

Result is this new Enum

```
package metaprogramovanie.test;
public final enum EnumTest{
a,b;
private java.lang.String r;
private static final metaprogramovanie.test.EnumTest[] $VALUES;

private EnumTest(java.lang.String arg0,int arg1){
}
public static metaprogramovanie.test.EnumTest[] values(){
return null;
}
public static metaprogramovanie.test.EnumTest valueOf(java.lang.String arg0){
return null;
}
private void some(){

}
public int daco(int arg0){
return 0;
}

}
```

As you can see there are som errors. For example Modifier generate FINAL and enum cant be final, next there are more methods and fields, constructor has paramaters ...

Constructor generate

```
private void writeConstructors(Class<?> cls, PrintWriter writer){
    Constructor[] cons = cls.getDeclaredConstructors();
    for (Constructor constructor : cons) {
        this.writeAnnotations(writer, constructor.getDeclaredAnnotations());
        writer.write(Modifier.toString(constructor.getModifiers()) + " " + cls.getSimpleName());
        this.writeParameters(writer,constructor.getParameters());
        writer.write("{");
        this.writeNewLine(writer);
        writer.write("}");
        this.writeNewLine(writer);
    }
}
```

Field generate

```
private void writeFields(Class<?> cls, PrintWriter writer){
    Field[] atr = cls.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : atr) {
        if(field.isEnumConstant()){
            System.out.println("JE");
        }
        else{
            this.writeAnnotations(writer, field.getDeclaredAnnotations());
            writer.write(Modifier.toString(field.getModifiers())+" " + field.getType().getTypeName()+ " " + field.getName());
            if(Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())){
                try{
                    Object value = field.get(null);
                    writer.write(" = " + this.getFieldValue(field));
                }catch(IllegalAccessException ex){

                }
            }
            writer.write(";");
            this.writeNewLine(writer);
        }
    }
    this.writeNewLine(writer);
}
```

Methods generate

```
 private void writeMethods(Class<?> cls, PrintWriter writer){
    Method[] methods = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method met : methods) {
        this.writeAnnotations(writer, met.getDeclaredAnnotations());
        writer.write(Modifier.toString(met.getModifiers())+" "+met.getReturnType().getTypeName() +" "+ met.getName());
        this.writeParameters(writer, met.getParameters());
        writer.write("{");
        this.writeNewLine(writer);
        if(!met.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE)){
            this.writeMethodBody(writer,met);
        }
        this.writeNewLine(writer);       
        writer.write("}");
        this.writeNewLine(writer);
    }
    this.writeNewLine(writer);
}
```

If you have any ideas how to get enum which can be compiled.

Comment: Where did the `daco` come from?

Comment: sry i copy it and rename on stackoverflow some2 is daco but i added [] dont know why i will change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explanation of why you get all the extra stuff.

Enums are implemented using a lot of code that is synthesized by the compiler, so that "behind the scenes" they behave as the Java Language Spec specifies, without requiring the JVM to be drastically changed.

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) says, for example, that:

- An `enum` is implicitly `final` unless there's a constant with a body.
- Any `enum` implicitly declares the methods `values()` and `valueOf(String)`.

For this reason, you got the `final` modifier for the `EnumTest`, and you got the two extra methods.

In addition, the compiler synthesizes some code to help implement some of the required stuff efficiently. For example, the source of the array to be copied and returned by the method `values()` is placed in a synthetic field named, in this case, `$VALUES`. It is filled up at the initialization of the enum, and then it can be copied whenever `values()` is called.

Also, to properly initialize the constants, the compiler adds two hidden parameters to each of the constructors. So if you have an empty constructor, behind the scenes it actually has two parameters - the constant's name and its ordinal number. If you have a constructor with one parameter, behind the scenes it will have 3 parameters.

There is additional synthetic code created when you have constants with their own bodies.

All of these latter implementations done by the compiler are **not** documented in the JLS and are basically left up to any compiler to decide how to implement. As long as the enum behaves correctly as a result of whatever code the compiler generates, it is free to generate it in any way it chooses.

---

Tips for overcoming some of the problems you have encountered:

- Instead of using `Modifier.toString(cls.getModifiers())` to print the `enum` modifiers, use

  ```
  Modifier.toString(cls.getModifiers() & ~ Modifier.FINAL & ~ Modifier.ABSTRACT)
  ```

  This excludes the `final` modifier from the output as well as the `abstract` modifier which will show up if you add abstract methods to the `enum` (and process the constant bodies, which is something you haven't done so far).
- Use the [`Field.isSynthetic()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#isSynthetic()) method to check whether a field is synthesized by the compiler, and do not output the fields for which this method returns `true`. This will get rid of the `$VALUES` field.
- The two methods `values()` and `valueOf(String)` are not considered synthetic and if you use `Method.isSynthetic()` on them, it will return false. So you'll simply have to check each method you find in the enum. If it is one of these two methods, with the signature and return type as specified in the JLS, skip them and do not output them.

The tricky part is getting rid of the two additional parameters of each of the constructors. Basically, when you iterate through the constructor parameters, you can skip the first two parameters. However, **remember that this will only work for code generated by the Oracle compiler and is not guaranteed in future versions or any other compiler**!